# Can i create a model on AWS Serverless Image Handler SIH?

Tags: amazon-web-services, image, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-serverless

I have to integrate a AWS Serverless Image Handler for optimization of my images.
but for optimization i want the URL of my images like that **https://xxxx.cloudfront.net/model_1/img.jpg** . Instead of using the Thumbor filter **https://xxxx.cloudfront.net/fit-in/150x150/img.jpg** I want to create a predefined template that has the modifications I want. Is it possible ?

I try the URL encoded but it's not suitable for me, what I want is to put the model